# Let $u=\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_i$, with $u_i \in \mathfrak{M}$ and $n>1$. Can we conclude that $u \in \mathfrak{M}^{n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

My question comes from Trèves, F. Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels.

Let $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ be the ring of the formal power in
one variable, $X$, with complex coefficients. Such a formal power series
is written
\begin{equation*}
 u=u(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_nX^n,
 \end{equation*} where the coefficients $u_n$ are complex numbers.
Addition and multiplication are immediately defined by
\begin{align*}
 u+v=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(u_n+v_n)X^n,
 uv=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{p=0}^{n}u_{n-p}v_{p} \right)X^n.
\end{align*}
Multiplication by scalars is defined in the obvious way:
\begin{equation*}
 \lambda u= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\lambda u_n)X^n.
\end{equation*}

It is easy to see that for a formal power series $u$ to have an inverse, it is necessary and sufficient that its first coefficient, $u_0$ , be different from zero.

Let us denote by $\mathfrak{M} $ the set of elements which do not have an inverse, that is to say the set of formal power series $u$ such that $u_0=0$.

For $n>1$ let us denote by $\mathfrak{M}^{n}$ the set of formal power series $u$ such that $u_p=0$ if $p<n$. Thus, if $u \in \mathfrak{M}^{n}$ we have that $u=u_nX^n+u_{n+1}X^{n+1}+\cdots=X^{n-1}(u_nX+u_{n+1}X^2+\cdots)=X^{n-1}u_1(X)$, where $u_1 \in \mathfrak{M}$. Since $v=X=0+1X^1+0+\cdots \in \mathfrak{M}$, we obtain that every element of $\mathfrak{M}^{n}$ is the product of $n$ elements from $\mathfrak{M}$.

**My question:** Let $u=\prod_{i=1}^{n}u_i$, with $u_i \in \mathfrak{M}$ and $n>1$. Can we conclude that $u \in \mathfrak{M}^{n}$?

Answer (score 1):

A formal power series $u$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$ iff $X\mid u$ (equivalently, $u=Xu'$). Then a product of $n$ powers series from $\mathfrak M$ is divisible by $X^n$, that is, belongs to $\mathfrak M^n$.

**Remark.** $\mathfrak M$ is an ideal in $\mathbb C[[X]]$, and a product of $n$ elements from $\mathfrak M$ belongs to $\mathfrak M^n$ by the definition of power of an ideal.